# MongoDB query to select documents with array with all of its elements matching some conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to come up with a query in MongoDB that lets me select documents in a collection based on the contents of subdocuments in a couple of levels deep arrays.

The collection in the example (simplified) represents situations. The purpose of the query is, given a moment in time, to know the currently active situation. The conditionGroups array represents different conditions in which the situation becomes active, and each of those has an array of conditions all of which have to be true.

In other words, the conditionGroups array operates as an OR condition, and its children array "conditions" operates as an AND. So, given any root document "situation", this situation will be active if at least one of its conditionGroups meets all of its conditions.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Weekdays",
    "conditionGroups": [
      {
        "conditions": [
          {
            "type": "DayOfWeek",
            "values": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
          },
          {
            "type": "HourIni",
            "values": [8]
          },
          {
            "type": "HourEnd",
            "values": [19]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Nights and weekends",
    "conditionGroups": [
      {
        "conditions": [
          {
            "type": "DayOfWeek",
            "values": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
          },
          {
            "type": "HourIni",
            "values": [20]
          },
          {
            "type": "HourEnd",
            "values": [23]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "conditions": [
          {
            "type": "DayOfWeek",
            "values": [6, 7]
          },
          {
            "type": "HourIni",
            "values": [8]
          },
          {
            "type": "HourEnd",
            "values": [19]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Weekend night",
    "conditionGroups": [
      {
        "conditions": [
          {
            "type": "DayOfWeek",
            "values": [6, 7]
          },
          {
            "type": "HourIni",
            "values": [20]
          },
          {
            "type": "HourEnd",
            "values": [23]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Another thing to note is that there are other types of conditions, like DayOfMonth, Month, Year, and others that might come, so the query should look for conditions that match the type and value or do not exist at all.

Given this example data, and imagining a december monday at lunchtime (so DayOfWeek is 1, current hour is 12, DayOfMonth is 13, Month is 12, Year is 2021) only the first document should be selected, because it has a "conditionGroup" all of which conditions match the current parameters, even if parameters like DayOfMonth/Year/Month are not specified. The important thing is that all the conditions must be met.

Now, I've tried the following with no luck:

```
db.situations.find({
  'conditionGroups': { $all: [
    {
      $elemMatch: { $nor: [
        { 'conditions.type': 'HourIni', 'conditions.values.0': { $gt: 12 } },
        { 'conditions.type': 'HourEnd', 'conditions.values.0': { $lte: 12 } },
        { 'conditions.type': 'DayOfWeek', 'conditions.values.0': { $nin: [1] } },
        { 'conditions.type': 'DayOfMonth', 'conditions.values.0': { $nin: [13] } },
        { 'conditions.type': 'Month', 'conditions.values.0': { $nin: [12] } },
        { 'conditions.type': 'Year', 'conditions.values.0': { $nin: [2021] } },
      ]}
    }
  ] }
})
```

This query is coming back empty.

Another thing I've tried is to first unwind the conditionGroups with the aggregation pipeline, and then try $elemMatch on conditions, but getting odd results. My guess is that I don't fully understand the $elemMatch and other array operators and I'm confusing them somehow...

It's quite a tricky question...so I've simplified it, but a largely appreciated bonus would be to consider that every condition, apart from "type" and "values" can also have an "inverse" boolean attribute that acts like a "not", so that condition would have to be "reversed".

I've spent many hours trying to get this to work but I'm kind of lost now. I understand the info might not be enough, so if anyone was able to give me a hint I could provide extra info if needed...

Any tip would be appreciated as I'm quite lost! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following in an aggregation pipeline:

1. `$unwind` `conditionGroups` for future processing/filtering
2. use a `$switch` to perform condition checking on the `condition` level. Set the result to be `true` if the condition is matched, otherwise set the result to be `false`. By using `$map`, you obtained a mapped boolean result for the `condition` array
3. `$allElementsTrue` to check if the result array in step 2 is all true; if true, that means one condition passed all matchings
4. use the `_id` to find back the `_id` of all original documents

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "dateInput": ISODate("2021-12-13T12:00:00Z")
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$conditionGroups"
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "matchedCondition": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$conditionGroups.conditions",
          "as": "c",
          "in": {
            "$switch": {
              "branches": [
                {
                  "case": {
                    $and: [
                      {
                        $eq: [
                          "$$c.type",
                          "DayOfWeek"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "$in": [
                          {
                            "$dayOfWeek": "$dateInput"
                          },
                          "$$c.values"
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "then": true
                },
                {
                  "case": {
                    $and: [
                      {
                        $eq: [
                          "$$c.type",
                          "HourIni"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "$gt": [
                          {
                            "$hour": "$dateInput"
                          },
                          {
                            "$arrayElemAt": [
                              "$$c.values",
                              0
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "then": true
                },
                {
                  "case": {
                    $and: [
                      {
                        $eq: [
                          "$$c.type",
                          "HourEnd"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "$lte": [
                          {
                            "$hour": "$dateInput"
                          },
                          {
                            "$arrayElemAt": [
                              "$$c.values",
                              0
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "then": true
                }
              ],
              default: false
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          true,
          {
            "$allElementsTrue": "$matchedCondition"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "originalDocument"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$originalDocument"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$originalDocument"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XN4yOfNvfrK) for your reference.